# grep or sed how to get apachectl -v out in bash

Tags: bash

My code is :

```
#!/bin/bash

strversion=`apache2ctl -v | awk '{print $3}' | sed  's/(Debian)//g;s/Server//g;s/built//g;s/2022-06-09T04:26:43//g'`

echo ${strversion%}
exit 0
```

i get this:

```
Apache/2.4.54
```

but i will have to look

```
Apache version 2.4.54
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the variable expansion is not quoted. An unquoted variable is subject to [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) (and [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion))

```
echo "Apache2 - ${strversion%')'}"
# ...^...........................^
```

See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Comment: i make a echo so i look i will, but the 
Server built:   2022-06-09T04:26:43
is not correct yet.

Comment: If you show the output of `apachectl -v` then we can help with the sed command.

Comment: how can we do it ???

Comment: ? Run `apache2ctl -v`, copy the output and paste it into your question

Comment: check the question now mate

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`strversion=$(apache2ctl -v | head -1 | awk -F '[ /]' '{printf "%s version %s", $3, $4}')`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).